# Dynamic content types: One table with many columns or one table for each?

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I run into this question from time to time and I was wondering what the best solution ultimately may be.

**Example:**

Let's use "dynamic forms" as an example here. You have a form editor and can add form fields (inputs). Each form field translates to a different type of data:

- A `<textarea>` becomes a `TEXT` column.
- An `<input type="text">` becomes a `VARCHAR(X)`.
- An `<input type="range">` becomes a `FLOAT`.
- A `<select>` could be a comma-separated list (`TEXT`), a separate table with each entry (foreign key) or a reference to an existing table (foreign key).

An easy way to store the **structure** of each for would probably be something like this:

[image]

That's all fine. But the real question is: How do we properly store the data, if someone would fill this dynamic form?

I see two solutions to this:

- A) Create a table, where there is a NULLable column for each expected data type (`VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, `FLOAT`, ...). This would work, but leaves a lot of ugly NULL values, since each form field value only occupies one column. Also, `<select>` fields would be problematic if they refer to an existing table.
- B) Create a table for each expected data type. This would keep things cleaner than version A, but require a lot more complexity when storing and fetching data, since the program has to know the type, use the right table, etc etc.

I'm wondering: are there better / other solutions to this? What's should be considered the better approach? I can imagine something like this coming up quite a lot - perhaps there's a third option I didn't know about?

Please keep in mind that the "form editor" example is just that - an *example*. This problem applies to many other things: a template editor, a settings editor, etc. I'm asking about a "general" approach with this problem, not specifically for form editors ;)

Note: I wouldn't consider using an additional non-relational database as a solution for this. I mainly want to keep the data in one place, so the question focuses on (My)SQL only.

Comment: You're not alone.

Comment: @Strawberry I figured. This thing keeps popping up again and again and everyone I know seems to have a different take on it - but none of them has a really "proper" solution.

Comment: *"This thing keeps popping up again and again and everyone I know seems to have a different take on it - but none of them has a really "proper" solution. –"* That is because this data/user case has nothing relational  @Katai these kind of things seams to be better suited for a [ODBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: There is no real question here, excet for the title itself, but as a question that's just way too broad and way too general.  Other than that, there is nothing else except one single "example" but then at the end we get "but note I'm not asking just about this specific example".  Brief : all of "too broad", "primarily opinion-based" and "unclear what you're asking" apply as a valid reason for closing.  I haven't checked the "duplicates" thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I'm asking about a "general" approach with this problem, not specifically for form editors*
>
> *This thing keeps popping up again and again and everyone I know seems to have a different take on it - but none of them has a really "proper" solution*

After the Relational requirement, which is of course the highest order directive, I will take **generic approach** and **proper solution** as over-arching directives.

## 1 Elevation to Relational

But first, a correction.  In order to elevate the data model to **Relational**, without which the rather straight-forward solution would be exceedingly complex (which is precisely why [a] there are so many incorrect methods, and [b] none of them are proper solutions).

The great bulk of "literature" and textbooks that is promoted and marketed as "relational" is in fact anti-relational.  Pre-1970 Record Filing Systems with relational labels, which is evidently all that the many authors and "theoreticians" can understand.  The main difference between such pre-relational filing systems and the *Relational Model* is, the references are logical, not physical.

- Whereas in pre-relational systems, **physical** records were related by physical pointers, such as `ID (INTEGER; GUID; UUID; etc)`, in the Relational paradigm, **logical** rows (not records) are related by Relational Key.
- A Relational Key is required to be made up from the data, which is logical, not physical (physical pointers are not data).

The Record IDs serve no purpose in a Relational database.  Their purpose is to propagate what the "theoreticians" understand:

- to confuse you
- to maintain a pre-1970, pre-relational, physical mindset
- and thus prevent a Relational mindset and database

At the least, each such `Record ID` will be one **additional** column and one **additional** index.

- *Additional*, not *instead of,* because the indices on the logical data (Keys) are required for data Integrity, otherwise you will have duplicates and no integrity.

Therefore, your requirement elevated to Relational, with one less column and one less index in each table:

[image: Katai 1]

#### Note

- All my data models are rendered in [IDEF1X](http://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/), the Standard for modelling Relational databases.

  - [IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf) for beginners
  - [IDEF1X Model Anatomy](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Model%20Anatomy.pdf) for the experienced, who are seeking a refresher

## 2 Relational Key that is Required

The second thing that needs to be understood is the **Intergrity Features** of Relational Keys, which you will not have, due to the "theoreticians" being blissfully unaware of it.  This is an explanation relevant to the Question, rather than a full tutorial.  Assuming that you do want Data Integrity and Relational Integrity (the logical feature provided by the *Relational Model* (as distinct from Referential Integrity, which is a physical facility provided by SQL).  Which we will need, in order to control (provide integrity to) the data structures that are required 'lower' in the data hierarchy, for "Storage".

- While the above [1] is correct for *that* purpose, we have an additional requirement: we need the `FieldType` ***in*** the `FormField.PK` such that it can be migrated to its child tables.
- But of course, we must not subtract from the logical `FormField.PK` above [1].  If we do, it would lose its integrity and meaning.
- So we:

  - add the Relational Key that is required [2]
  - make it **Primary Key** because that is what is migrated
  - and we maintain the original Primary Key [1] by making it an **Alternate Key**
  - which changes the relation `FieldType::FormField` from **Non-Identifying** to **Identifying**.

[image: Katai 2]

## 3 Relational Solution • Subtype

Now the solution is straightforward.

> I see two solutions to this [A] or [B]

Definitely [B], with a couple of improvements to bring it up to Standard.

[A] is an unnormalised mess that has no integrity, and it will be a maintenance nightmare.  Nulls are very problematic, Nulls in a Foreign Key is suicide.

> but [B] will require a lot more complexity when storing and fetching data, since the program has to know the type, use the right table, etc etc.

#### Storage

Not at all.

- Bear with me, the solution is below
- You clearly understand that the data ("storage") tables have to be typed (or cast)
- It requires an ordinary **Exclusive Subtype** structure.  (We have had Subtypes in DBMSs since the 1960's.)
- I have provided that typing (casting) control in the Basetype

  - first, by inserting `FieldType` in the parent `FormField` Primary Key, so that it will be migrated
  - second, by using a Non-Identifying relation, so that it is not in the Key of the child `UserField`
  - but it remains non-key column, and it is available as a **Discriminator** for the Basetype
- Now, it is possible to understand why [1][ and [2] had to be implemented first
- See if you can appreciate the Relational Integrity (as distinct from Referential Integrity) that Relational Keys provide:

  - `UserField` is `CONSTRAINED` to `FieldNames` that exist in the applicable `FormName`
  - that level of logical data integrity, which is standard fare in Relational databases, cannot be had in the pre-relational physical (`Record ID` based) filing systems that the "theoreticians" fraudulently market as "relational"
- [Subtype Exposition](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Subtype.pdf) for beginners

Further, you should be using ACID Transactions (a requirement for SQL Compliance since the first release), not `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` directly from the program.  That would simplify both the app and the program code, as well as eliminate the otherwise thousands of errors.  If implemented to OLTP Standard, it minimises locking and contention, and reduces, if not eliminates, deadlocks.

#### Retrieval

Not really.  It may not be simple, it is definitely not complex, but it is straight-forward.

- Use `VIEW` (this is a classic use of `VIEWS`)

  - for retrieving a known Subtype:
    one View for each Subtype
  - for retrieving an unknown Subtype:
    one View (with an `UNION`) for **any** Subtype (which will return just one for each Basetype, whichever Subtype it is)
    (This is not a "supertype", the anti-relational concept beloved of the "theoreticians", heaven forbid.)
- That will make the SQL coding also straight-forward.

[image: Katai 3]

#### One More

- [All Data Models in a single PDF](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Katai%20TA.pdf).

Comment: I wanted to thank you for your effort, your answer is a very interesting read and definitely goes into the direction I expected. I knew that [A] wouldn't be an acceptable solution at all and always opted for something like [B], in a similar fashion as you suggest. I'll see on how to implement your approach. You really seem to like all those "theoreticians" ;) /s

Comment: @Katai You are welcome.  Feel free to ask questions (the related Q's & A's do have all sorts of weird and wonderful, but grossly incorrect, info ... which leads to crazy SQL code).  That is the legacy of the "theoreticians" who promote anti-relational as "relational".  You really need to understand Subtypes as a concept (refer to the links, and the links in the links), something they know nothing about.

Comment: Which "theoreticians" do you have in mind, who are "blissfully unaware" of the integrity features of Relational Keys? The people I can think of who seem willfully (rather than blissfully) unaware are: vendors who worry that implementing the full SQL Standard will hit performance; and DBAs, ditto. By full Standard I mean supporting `CHECK` declarative constraints, rather than forcing user sites to write ad-hoc `TRIGGER`/`INSTEAD OF` code -- which usually turns out worse for efficiency.

Comment: This answer has some good material, but also a great deal of opinion, which I find highly controversial, prejudiced and historically inaccurate. For example, Date & Darwen's textbooks, or the Alice book do accurately portray the relational model; whereas Codd's own writings after about 1975 are far from his best work and should be ignored.

Comment: @AntC 1) It doesn't matter what anyone thinks (opinion), it is a matter of evidenced fact, logic, science.  Date's; Date & Darwen's; the "Alice" books, all contradict the Codd's *Relational Model*, while purporting to be "relational".  They falsely demean Codd, as you slavishly do.  They cannot Normalise anything.  2) You are free to implement my data model, and **add** `Record ID` columns and indices as they prescribe, which do nothing except confuse you.  Or worse, remove the logical indices, which they do not prescribe, and allow duplicates (which are prohibited in the *RM*).

Comment: @AntC Read the *RM* for yourself, instead of relying on the misrepresentaions of said "theoreticians". [Codd's Relational Model](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Codd%20E%20F/A%20Relational%20Model%20of%20Data%20for%20Large%20Shared%20Data%20Banks.pdf)

Comment: Why is this an answer? A lengthy and mildly entertaining rant on relational philosophy is one thing, but how is the data actually stored, and why? Isn't this just another excuse for a "god table"?

Comment: @david.pfx Evidently it is the Answer, because the seeker selected it.  Data is stored by a DBMS platform, in response to commands. If you need *How to translate a data model [diagram] to text* (eg. `CREATE TABLE` etc commands), please open a new Question.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: the questions were "how do we properly store the data" and "are there other better solutions" in a "general approach". You answered neither, and your answer is specific to the detail. If it were my question, I would reject your answer outright and hope to get something that addressed those points directly.

Comment: @david.pfx  *"You answered neither"*: OP understands **his** question, that  the general; the specific; the storage, has been answered, and that it is a better solution.  The delta, the gap, is between what the question really is, and what you think it is. It is not possible for me to address that, only you can figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

> can add form fields (inputs).

Let's remember the Relational Model is for representing 'structured information'.

If you can freely add (something) it sounds like you have unstructured information.

Where are these form fields coming from? Do they represent business entities, or attributes of entities? Then don't you already have those in a data model for the business? (Using 'business' in a very general sense.)

> But the real question is: How do we properly store the data, ...

No, the real question is: how do we properly retrieve/query the data? What does the data represent? What questions are the business users going to ask about it?

If you haven't already modelled the business entities/attributes, then you won't know how or even whether you can answer the users' questions.

So if users are just going to throw random facts/fields at the database and expect to ask random questions about it, you don't have structured data, and a Relational Database is not the right tool for the job. That sounds more like NoSQL or some sort of document/tagged/XML/JSON database. (Although I'd dispute whether "database" is the right term for those.)

Comment: My attempt to clarify: It's not that they throw random fields / data at the database, it's more that one table (example "forms") are connected to dozens of similar-but-different types of data. All these "types" are known and well defined, it's just that normalizing them down would add dozens of similar tables to the database with "indirect refences" (solution [B]). I was wondering if, in general, there are better approaches to this type of problem. The "free adding" refers to the amount (count) of entities not being defined. The entities themselves are defined.

Comment: Your q says you're using "dynamic forms" merely as an example. Now you're saying you already have all the business data held in a structured database: "The entities themselves are defined." You're duplicating from database fields to build or process a form. Then the forms data is transient/program-internal; it doesn't need to be in a database duplicating what's in the, um ... database. I'm not seeing a general difficulty here. _If_ "dynamic forms" is just one example, please give several more examples. (Add to the O.P.)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I've been unclear: When I say "the entities are defined", I still mean in the context of the example. So, if the example is a form, all possible "field types" are known. If the example is a template, all "template snippets" are known, etc. I'll try to clarify my O.P. tomorrow or so.